# What counts as a "structure"?

Tags: tooth-and-tail

In the fourth or fifth mission, the Heroic objective is to win without building any structures. However, you start with a single Gristmill and 4 farms, so getting food is pretty slow going.

There are a handful of unclaimed Gristmills around the map, but claiming them is essentially rebuilding them, so I'm not sure if this counts as building a structure. Additionally, am I allowed to create farmland?

I'm under the assumption that creating Warrens for units counts as structures, I'm just unsure what all is considered a "structure".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember doing that mission few weeks ago so this comes from personal experience.
You **can** actually claim gristmills and build farms! The only things you can't build are **warrens** and the **Bullet Hive** ( but also **defensive structures** in general ).